# Nearby Messages Api status bar notification callback

Tags: android, google-api, google-nearby

Currently when you activate nearby message api from your app, you will receive notification on the status bar, and there's a button "stop" and "setting", and if you explicitly click "stop" nearby messages will stop, my question is how to receive that stop action under my app perhaps using broadcast receiver, but i don't know what action should i put on intent filter ?

Second, i noticed that even though i disconnected googleApiClient on my "onStop" nearby is still active, is that really how it works ?

Comment: I'm wondering the answer to this as well. My two hunches are that either you will get a callback via GoogleApiClient.onConnectionSuspended() or possibly a callback on from PublishOptions.PublishCallback.onExpired() (and the equivalent for subscribe()), although, neither of those seems to explicitly say in the documentation that stopping via the notification will cause these to fire.

Comment: i do think so, using onExpired maybe the best solution so far... but i really need to determine whether nearby messages is still subscribing or publishing when it came from background

Comment: Did you find out if either of these callbacks worked when hitting the stop button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you click stop on the notification, 
   PublishOptions.PublishCallback.onExpired() will be called for publishes and the Subscribecallback.onExpired() for subscribes.

   You can find the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/PublishCallback#public-constructors).
2. When you disconnect from GoogleApiClient, active publishes and subscribes will automatically be stopped and cleaned up. In the interest of code clarity and belt-and-suspenders redundancy, Google recommendeds you explicitly unpublish or unsubscribe in your Activity's onStop() method.  See https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/pub-sub

Comment: The second point is not in my experience. I have recurring problems with an app that are costing me many hours because Nearby will not allways stop. If it would just stop when the GoogleApiClient was disconnected that would be great.
Only in some rare cases Nearby never stops. That is why I made my messages short but know the notification keeps flickering :(

Comment: I tested it and disconnecting from GoogleApiClient is not enough.

Comment: Would you mind providing logcat that shows it's still working after disconnect?  I'm curious what caused you to think that it's still sticking around?  


There could be some unknown cases that caused this leakage that you've experienced.

Comment: I must note I still use Play Services 8.3 because when I change it to the latest version the Nearby functionality completely stops working. So maybe it is a bug or something. I still don't know how to reproduce the problem. It happens sometimes when the app was active for a long time.

Comment: complement: When I unpublish and unsubscribe everything I cannot reproduce it: it occurs only very rarely (but enough for the client to not accept the solution), when I only disconnect for GoogleApiClient it allways stays active.

Comment: Can you expand on why updating to latest version, things broke for you.  ie. what errors are you getting?  If possible can you turn on these verbose loggings

$ adb shell setprop log.tag.NearbyMessages VERBOSE
$ adb shell setprop log.tag.copresGcore VERBOSE